# How can I disable the AdaptiveSubmitAction button once activated?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, double-click, adaptive-cards

I'm using "microsoft bot builder" library to build a bot in c#.

I have a card that contains an AdaptiveSubmitAction button which will present a new card on click.

I want to **disable** the submit button once its activated.. how would that be possible?

This is a part of my code:

```
        ////// Submit and Finish button ///////
        card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveColumnSet()
        {
            Columns = new List<AdaptiveColumn>()
            {
                new AdaptiveColumn()
                {
                    Width = "auto",
                    Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                    {
                        new AdaptiveActionSet()
                        {
                            Actions = new List<AdaptiveAction>()
                            {
                                new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
                                {
                                    Title = "Submit",
                                    Id = "Submit",
                                    //from the data you can trigger actions
                                    //e.g.: 
                                    Data = new {isDone = false, deleteCrit = false}
                                },
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                new AdaptiveColumn()
                {
                    Width = "auto",
                    Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                    {
                        new AdaptiveActionSet()
                        {
                            Actions = new List<AdaptiveAction>()
                            {
                                new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
                                {
                                    Title = "End",
                                    Id = "Finished",
                                    Data = new {isDone = true, deleteCrit = false}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        });
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney !! yes , Microsoft Teams is the channel i'm using.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is impossible because neither Adaptive Cards nor Teams has a concept of a double click when it comes to submit actions. If you were using Web Chat then you might be able to build a custom solution but Teams does not allow for that kind of customizability. If you need a submit action to function in multiple possible ways then I recommend using two different submit actions instead.

You can send feedback to Teams through the Teams app directly or you can submit feature requests in the [Teams docs repo](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues) or the [Adaptive Cards repo](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues).

Comment: Aha, thanks for the info! Just wanna note that I'm not focused on the double click concept as much as I care about disabling the submit action button from working once its clicked.. this is my major goal.

Comment: In the future, it would probably be a good idea to ask questions you actually want to know the answer to. Given that you asked about double-clicking, are you willing to upvote and accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should be possible, I believe you can update the Adaptive card view after the first click with only change in view being that the button will be in disabled view. Not only this you can make any change in the card and it will retroactively refresh the view of that card ID. For usage, see context.updateactivity and it's implementation details.